# PHP: выполнение SQL-запроса в цикле foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется код

```
$s= $data['s'];
        $s= explode(",",$s);
        $items = array();
        foreach($s $row) {
            $items = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='{$row}'");
        }
```

При вар дампе `items` выдает только 1 элемент, как весь результат цикла склеить в один массив?

Comment: Не стоит делать запросы в цикле. Повесите и сервер и базу

Answer (score 3):

Массив следует заполнять при помощи [], т.е. вместо `$items =`, следует писать `$items[] =`

```
$s= $data['s'];
$s= explode(",",$s);
$items = array();
foreach($s $row) {
  $items[] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='{$row}'");
}
```

Однако лучше не выполнять запросы в циклах. Самым разумным будет собрать в массив `$items` значения `$row`, а потом воспользоваться ключевым словом `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1, 5, 6, 8)
```

Объединить значения из `$items` в строку для `IN` можно при помощи функции `implode()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = explode(",", $data['s']);
$s = array_map('intval', $s);
$items = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN(" . implode(', ', $s) . ")");
```